# photoswipe keep flicker for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I have set up photoswipe for mobile device, it's working fine apart from the photos keep Flicker when swipe on the phone, but its working fine on computer. any idea how to fix please? cheers

the example will be: 
http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html

code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 


    <title>test/title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://computersforpeople.info/websites/scripts/jquery/lib/klass.min.js"></script>  
    <link href="http://computersforpeople.info/websites/scripts/jquery/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://computersforpeople.info/websites/scripts/jquery/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.4.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe)
        {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#gallery a").photoSwipe(
                {
                    enableMouseWheel: false,
                    enableKeyboard: false
                });

                $("#gallery a:first").click();
            });
        }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));





</script>




<script type="text/javascript">

$('a').live('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( !$this.attr('rel') || $this.attr('rel') != 'external' )
        $(document.getElementById( $this.attr('href') )).remove();
});


</script>

</head> 

<body> 


<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back" >
<div data-role="header" >
        <h1 style="white-space:normal">Apartment Specialists</h1>

  </div>
  <ul  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
        <li><a href="http://mobilecityleaders.smartagent.co.nz/users/262/properties">Feature Apartments</a></li>

                <ul data-role="listview"  data-filter="false" id="test-more">


  <div id="gallery" >

          <a href="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222204_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=350x262&s=732bf1b52c70b0fc" > <img src="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222204_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=120x90&s=e4501ebdfd60d8db" alt="" /></a>

          <a href="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222208_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=350x262&s=293a3a114859a240" > <img src="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222208_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=120x90&s=c599ece1364cfafe" alt="" /></a>

          <a href="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222213_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=350x262&s=da0802cfe1060df4" > <img src="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222213_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=120x90&s=f4b0ffaea30f6a2b" alt="" /></a>

          <a href="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222218_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=350x262&s=a54d15c8570f1d2b" > <img src="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222218_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=120x90&s=767b0330b9cf2f1e" alt="" /></a>

          <a href="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222223_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=350x262&s=9e2db11b4d87f798" > <img src="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222223_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=120x90&s=e9f8871520333fbe" alt="" /></a>

          <a href="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222227_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=350x262&s=2cd999589c41d34d" > <img src="http://prod.computersforpeople.info/media/2012/12/03/222227_46921.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=120x90&s=1af459b7ecc85dbe" alt="" /></a>


</div>  
<br /> 

<p align="center">
 <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Back</font></a></p>



    </ul>
    <br />


<li><a href="http://mobilecityleaders.smartagent.co.nz/users/264/properties">All Apartments</a></li>


</ul>

    <div data-role="footer" align="center">

    <h6 style="font-size: 55%;font-family:calibri">
  RE/MAX Leaders Real Estate (1987) Ltd Licensed Under REAA 2008</h6>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

    </div>  

<!-- /page -->





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just sort it. use code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js rather the version of 3.0.4. thanks